# How do I partially match a word using * in Vim VS Code?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

I am able to match identical words by placing my curser on a word and hitting * to find the next match. Can I match subsets of words using * functionality?

For example could I use * to navigate through the the following words:

computer
computer__phone
computer__printer

Answer (score 2):

Note that you want *two* different commands: first, search for the word under cursor (including partial matches); then search for the last pattern used.

So you need <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> etc. See `:h g*` and `:h g#`.

Comment: Great insight! Using the g*nn strategy I am able to start on _computer_ and find a partial match in _computer__phone_. If I start on the word _computer_ in _computer__phone_ is it possible to match the _computer_ substring in _computer__printer_?

Comment: @Matt_James You can always fall back to a regular search: `/computer` and then `n` `n` `n`...

Comment: @Matt_James Or you can copy some text and then paste it into search line, like: `/<C-R>"<CR>`. See `:h c_CTRL-R`.